# Android ListView with custom autosize Textview - some items not showing properly until scroll

Tags: listview, scroll, textview, android-cursoradapter, autosize

I found that similar topic has been solved here multiple times, but I was unable to find a solution for my problem.
I am using a ListView with custom CursorAdapter, which takes data from a database. The rows are created by XML file based on a custom Relative Layout, which has an image as a background and it is supposed to keep the aspect ratio of the image. The width of the Relative Layout is set to match_parent and the height is then calculated from the aspect ratio of the image.
In the Relative Layout there are 5 items (in fact there are 6 of them, the 6th one is an empty View just separating the row into two halves): 1 ImageView and 4 custom Text Views, which are modified to auto size the text depending on the height of the TextView (the size of the text is set as a percentage, here the parameter heightPercentage is 0.5, so the size of the text should be 50% of the TextView's height).
 
Everything seems to work, but sometimes a few of the items are not rendered properly (the text size seems to be correct, but the width of the TextView is too short. After scrolling a few items down and then back everything is fine.
Here are the photos:
Correct one (after scroll): 
[image: Correct]
Incorrect one (before scroll) 
[image: Incorrect]
**Edit:**
I've tried to use some of the autosize textviews found on the internet and the behaviour is more or less similar; sometimes the view is not rendered properly until scroll ocurrs, or it is rendered properly at first, but after scroll it is messed up... it seems to me, that there are some specific rules for custom views used in Listview rows which I do not understand :-( I've tried to put methods like invalidateViews(), notifyDataSetChanged() to different places of code, sometimes even like runInIOThread(), but with no success, the behaviour is never changed...

Below is the code of the Custom Relative Layout called RelativeLayoutKeepRatio, custom TextView called WidthResizeTextView and custom CursorAdapter called MyCWGCursorAdapter.

```
public class RelativeLayoutKeepRatio extends RelativeLayout {
private float aspectRatio = 0; 
private ViewGroup.LayoutParams mLayoutParams = null;

public RelativeLayoutKeepRatio(Context context) {
    super(context);

}

public RelativeLayoutKeepRatio(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    aspectRatio = getAspectRatio(context, attrs);
}

public RelativeLayoutKeepRatio(Context context, AttributeSet attrs,
        int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    aspectRatio = getAspectRatio(context, attrs);
}

private float getAspectRatio(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
{
    TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.LayoutKeepRatio);
    float aspectRatio = a.getFloat(R.styleable.LayoutKeepRatio_aspectRatio, 0);
    if (aspectRatio == 0)
    {
        Drawable bg = getBackground();
        if (bg != null)
        {
            int mBgWidth = bg.getIntrinsicWidth();
            int mBgHeight = bg.getIntrinsicHeight();
            aspectRatio = (float)mBgWidth / (float)mBgHeight;
        }
    }
    return aspectRatio;
}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    if (mLayoutParams == null) {
        mLayoutParams = getLayoutParams();
    }

    int width = 0;
    int height = 0;

    //the width is known and we want to calculate the height
    if ((mLayoutParams.width == ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT ||
         mLayoutParams.width == 0
        ) &&
        mLayoutParams.height == ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)
    {
            width = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
            height = calculateHeight(width, aspectRatio);           
    //the height is known and we want to calculate the width
    } else if ((mLayoutParams.height == ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT ||
            mLayoutParams.height == 0
            ) &&
            mLayoutParams.width == ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)
    {
        height = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
        width = calculateWidth(width, aspectRatio);
    }

    else //the width and height are known, we do not need to calculate anything
    {
        width = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
        height = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
    }

    int mode = MeasureSpec.EXACTLY;
    super.onMeasure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(width, mode),
            MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(height, mode));
}

private int calculateWidth(int height, float aspectRatio)
{
    return (int)((float) height * aspectRatio);
}

private int calculateHeight(int width, float aspectRatio)
{
    return (int)((float) width / aspectRatio);
}
}
```

```
public class WidthResizeTextView extends TextView {
private float heightPercentage = 0; 

public WidthResizeTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.ResizeTextView);
    heightPercentage = a.getFloat(R.styleable.ResizeTextView_HeightPercentage, 0);
}

public WidthResizeTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.ResizeTextView);
    heightPercentage = a.getFloat(R.styleable.ResizeTextView_HeightPercentage, 0);
}

public WidthResizeTextView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public float getHeightPercentage(){
    return heightPercentage;
}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    String text = getText().toString();

    int height = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
    int mode = MeasureSpec.getMode(heightMeasureSpec);
    if (mode == MeasureSpec.EXACTLY){
        setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, (int)((float)height * heightPercentage));
        int neededWidth = (int)getPaint().measureText(text);
        super.onMeasure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(neededWidth, mode),
                MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(height, mode));
    }
    else
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    }
}
```

```
public class MyCWGCursorAdapter extends CursorAdapter {
String path = null;
Typeface face = null;
public MyCWGCursorAdapter(Context context, Cursor c, int flags) {
    super(context, c, flags);
    path = CommonUtils.getAppPath(context);
    face = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/CANDARA.TTF");
}

@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    RelativeLayout row = (RelativeLayout)inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false);
    ViewWrapper wrapper = new ViewWrapper(row);
    row.setTag(wrapper);
    return (row);
}

@Override
public void bindView(View row, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ViewWrapper wrapper = (ViewWrapper)row.getTag();
    String nick = cursor.getString(1);
    String fileName = cursor.getString(2);
    int count = cursor.getInt(3);

    Bitmap bitmap = CommonUtils.applyCircleMask(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path + fileName));
    if (bitmap == null)
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.empty_cwg);
    ImageView picture = wrapper.getImageView();
    picture.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

    WidthResizeTextView nickLabel = wrapper.getNickLabel();
    nickLabel.setTypeface(face);

    WidthResizeTextView nickTextView = wrapper.getNickTextView();
    nickTextView.setText(nick);
    nickTextView.setTypeface(face);

    WidthResizeTextView countLabel = wrapper.getCountLabel();
    countLabel.setTypeface(face);

    WidthResizeTextView countTextView = wrapper.getCountTextView();
    countTextView.setText("" + count);
    countTextView.setTypeface(face);

}

class ViewWrapper {
    View base;
    ImageView imageView = null;
    WidthResizeTextView nickLabel = null;
    WidthResizeTextView nickTextView = null;
    WidthResizeTextView countLabel = null;
    WidthResizeTextView countTextView = null;

    ViewWrapper(View base){
        this.base = base;
    }
    ImageView getImageView(){
        if (imageView == null){
            imageView = (ImageView)base.findViewById(R.id.CWGView);
        }
        return imageView;
    }

    WidthResizeTextView getNickLabel(){
        if (nickLabel == null) {
            nickLabel = (WidthResizeTextView)base.findViewById(R.id.nickLabel);
        }
        return nickLabel;
    }

    WidthResizeTextView getNickTextView() {
        if (nickTextView == null) {
            nickTextView = (WidthResizeTextView)base.findViewById(R.id.nickTextView);
        }
        return nickTextView;
    }

    WidthResizeTextView getCountLabel(){
        if (countLabel == null) {
            countLabel = (WidthResizeTextView)base.findViewById(R.id.countLabel);
        }
        return countLabel;
    }

    WidthResizeTextView getCountTextView() {
        if (countTextView == null) {
            countTextView = (WidthResizeTextView)base.findViewById(R.id.countTextView);
        }
        return countTextView;
    }
}

}
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.asharp.android.CWGs.RelativeLayoutKeepRatio
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.asharp.android.CWGs"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/cwg_mycwg_bg" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/CWGView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="5dip"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" 
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"     
            android:src="@drawable/empty_cwg" />

        <com.asharp.android.CWGs.WidthResizeTextView
            android:id="@+id/nickLabel"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_above="@+id/spacer"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/CWGView"
            android:bufferType="spannable"
            android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="@string/nick"
            android:ellipsize="none"
            android:textColor="@color/MyCWG_field_names"
            custom:HeightPercentage="0.5" />

        <com.asharp.android.CWGs.WidthResizeTextView
            android:id="@+id/nickTextView"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/countLabel"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_above="@+id/spacer"
            android:layout_marginLeft = "10dip"
            android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
            android:text="0"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:ellipsize="none"
            android:bufferType="spannable"
            custom:HeightPercentage="0.5"
            android:background="#00FF00"
            android:textColor="@color/MyCWG_field_values"/>
        <View
            android:id="@+id/spacer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/CWGView"
            android:layout_height="1px"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:visibility="invisible"/>            
        <com.asharp.android.CWGs.WidthResizeTextView
            android:id="@+id/countLabel"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@id/spacer"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
            android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/CWGView"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:text="@string/count_colon"
            android:ellipsize="none"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textColor="@color/MyCWG_field_names"
            android:bufferType="spannable"
            custom:HeightPercentage="0.5" />
        <com.asharp.android.CWGs.WidthResizeTextView
            android:id="@+id/countTextView"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/countLabel"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_below="@id/spacer"
            android:layout_marginLeft = "10dip"
            android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:ellipsize="none"
            android:bufferType="spannable"
            custom:HeightPercentage="0.5"
            android:text="0"
            android:textColor="@color/MyCWG_field_values"/>


</com.asharp.android.CWGs.RelativeLayoutKeepRatio>
```

Has anyone of you seen such behaviour? I spent a few days trying to solve this out, but I was not succesful :-( I believe it has something to do with the WidthResizeTextView, because it took me a long time to put it to work at least like this. Thank you for help!

Comment: @user2582585: From your edit, it seems that this is your own post, but before you have logged on as user2579825. You should only be using one account. To set this straight, follow the instructions on this help page: http://stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts

Answer (score 0):

You might want to redesign your XML using standard Views like

- a `ConstraintLayout` instead of a `RelativeLayout` as container
- `Guidelines` or percent height/width to position your widgets

Have a look at to the [ConstraintLayout documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout.html).